# How to set the core.editor to Coda 2

Tags: git, editor, config, coda

Is there a way to use Coda 2 as my core.editor when I use the GIT trough the terminal (I am on a Macbook with OsX Mountain Lion). The fallowing command does not work:
`git config --global core.editor "Coda 2"`

I found some scripts here and there on the internet (coda 1), but those did't work for me. It's not that much of a problem to use vim (basic understand of using 'i' for insert mode, esc for leaving and using ":wq" for writing and quiting.), but would still be nice to configure it.

Is there also a way to use Kaleidoscope as my 'diff' tool?

I have to say that I am just starting to learn to use the terminal, but I am no pro (Know simple things like cd/pwd/ls/rm/mkdir thats it really). Also I have a git gui (Tower), but I want to learn to use the 'raw' git terminal first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justin Hileman's "Coda-CLI-Shell integration for Coda" should do the trick. Once installed you should be able to open files and directories from the terminal (inside and outside of the Coda 2 app). See: http://justinhileman.info/coda-cli/

Comment: Tnx, this looks really promising! I will try it out as soon as possible.